# Cannot run java jar on ubuntu

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

So I would like to run a jar application on Ubuntu, but for some reason, it doesn't work in unexpected ways...

First:

```
java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_151"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-8u151-b12-0ubuntu0.16.04.2-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

And here's what I get when I try to run something...

```
java -jar ./runnable-texturepacker.jar OR
java -jar runnable-texturepacker.jar 
-> Usage: inputDir [outputDir] [packFileName] [settingsFileName]
```

Running just the beginning gives...

```
java -jar
Error: -jar requires jar file specification
...
```

Wierd!

Comment: What were you expecting `java - jar` to do if you don't specify a jar file to go with it? Automatically run all jars in the directory??

Comment: It's not "weird".
Q: Did you supply requested command line arguments (`inputDir`, etc.)?  PS: the double-negative "it doesn't work in unexpected ways" implies that it's working exactly as expected.  I agree :)

Comment: The jar is running and telling you that you're supposed to give it parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this looks like a Java JVM error message, it's not.

If you were to [read the docs](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Texture-packer#packing) for the library you've posted, those are actually input arguments to the Java application itself, not the JVM.

If you were to go further and [read the source](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/c8aeb0aa4e4a86c67e1fa89b710cb144b2e203e9/extensions/gdx-tools/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tools/texturepacker/TexturePacker.java#L861) you would find that exact err message.

```
System.out.println("Usage: inputDir [outputDir] [packFileName] [settingsFileName]");
```

**Solution**

Read the manual for the tools you try to use.